# Creating file from res.end(data, 'binary') makes the file corrupted

Tags: node.js, sendgrid-api-v3

In our application, an excel is created using 'excel-export' module in one API.

```
var nodeExcel = require('excel-export');
var result = nodeExcel.execute(conf);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformates');
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition",    "attachment;filename="+ "abcd.xlsx");
res.end(result, 'binary');
```

I am consuming this API in another API where this excel file has to be sent in a mail as attachment. We are using Sendgrid v3 REST API for mail sending.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('abc.xlsx');
var options1 = { method: 'GET',
        url: <api url>,
        encoding: 'binary'
        };    
request(options1, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);    
    response.pipe(file);        
    var avi = JSON.stringify(file);
    var buff = new Buffer.from(avi).toString('base64');
    var options = { method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send',
                headers:
                    { 'content-type': 'application/json',
                      'authorization': <####> },
                body:
                    { personalizations:
                        [ { to: <####>,
                        subject: <#####> ],
                        from: <####>,
                        content: <####>,
                        attachments: [ { content: buff, filename: 'abc.xlsx' } ] },
                        json: true };
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
});
```

The mail is being sent but when I am trying to open the excel it is giving error that the file is corrupted. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The trick was in using encoding : null instead of encoding: 'binary'. Also instead of

```
response.pipe(file);        
var avi = JSON.stringify(file);
var buff = new Buffer.from(avi).toString('base64');
```

I used

```
var buff = new Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');
```